# Possible to add a organic group role programmatically?

Tags: organic-groups, users

Im trying to programmatically add OG group roles and assign permissions through an update hook. Is this possible?

Comment: You asking to add a new og role by programmatic way?not adding existing og role to a user, right?

Comment: thats correct, I'd like to add a new og role programmatically

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [hook_og_default_roles()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21og%21og.api.php/function/hook_og_default_roles/7) will only **assign** the role to new group members. The role must first exist in the roles table. You can do this by creating it in the OG UI or by using og_role_create() and og_role_save () as above.

Comment: Sorry correction. It does use this hook but only on the **first** time an entity group type (bundle) is created. The code checks that roles exist for the group type and returns if it finds them, so after they are created for the first instance of a group type it never calls the hook again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a role, the recommended way is through [hook_og_default_roles()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.api.php/function/hook_og_default_roles/7). This will add the og role when the module is enabled.

If you have to add it in an update or only when a certain condition is met, then you can use the API function [og_role_create()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21og%21og.module/function/og_role_create/7) (using only the first parameter) and og_role_save().

Permissions can be created through hook_og_permission() and granted to the role with og_role_grant_permissions().